# Request data from other apps iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have two apps in iPhone, eg. App1 and App2. App1 needs to get data which is stored in App2. I'm trying to use URL Schemes to achieve that. Can anybody suggest me how to do that?

Comment: WHich bit do you want help with? The URL schemes or the mechanics of the exchange?

Answer (score 2):

Just use like you said custom URL schemes and pass the data into the URL.
There is no other way, other passing the data in the URL scheme

Comment: If using a URL scheme and the data is particularly sensitive, you'd do better to pass some kind of token on the URL and then when authenticating back in the app, it will fetch the sensitive data over SSL.

Answer (score 1):

Having no idea about the type of data your trying to share:

I would also say that you might want to use a server in between.  App1 would then store the data to the server, then call the app URL of app2.  This triggers app2 to go fetch data from the server.

This is a trade-off of course.  It allows you to have a lot more control over the data, but at the cost of a much more complex system.

Like I said, I do not know what the data is that your trying to transfer.

Comment: I only want to send simple plain text between apps. Thank for your replies. URL Schemes is the best solution for my project